# .htaccess закрытие директории

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как реализовать на .htaccess .. если директория закрыта (образно директория private) то переадресовывается на index.php в главную директорию?
www

-index.php

private

```
     --некие файлы
     -- некие php файлы
```

css

```
     --стили css
```

Comment: А что значит "директория закрыта"? Это как определяется? Тем, что в ней лежит этот `.htaccess` или как-то ещё? И как поступать с поддиректориями?

Comment: к примеру есть директория (папка) с содержимым которая не должна отображаться при переходе в неё через адресную строку а должен произойти редирект на index.php -

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в другом: по каким критериям определяется "закрытость"? Наличием в ней файла `.htaccess` или как-то ещё? И как поступать с ***под***директориями?

Comment: .htaccess  есть и что бы в нём не писал я - то просто происходит скрытие содержимого , делал redirect на ../index.php  толку Ноль , с содержимым и подкоталогами без разницы что делать ,php всё равно прочитает (так же ? прочитает ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы при попытке захода в какой-либо каталог происходило перенаправление к файлу `index.php`, расположенному в корневом каталоге сайта, можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Перенаправление будет действовать также и для любого подкаталога.

Если же надо выйти из этого каталога не в корень сайта, а просто на один уровень вверх, то нужно изменить `RewriteBase`. Например, если `.htaccess` лежит в каталоге `/test1/test2`, то можно использовать следующее правило:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test1/test2

RewriteRule .* ../index.php [R=301,L]
```

При входе в каталог `test2` или любой его подкаталог произойдёт перенаправление на `/test1/index.php`.

Чтобы разрешить выполнение файлов `.php` из данного каталога (и всех его подкаталогов), а все остальные перенаправлять, можно сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !.*\.php$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Можно также разрешить доступ к нескольким типам файлов, но условие нужно будет записать в более сложной форме:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Такой `.htaccess` разрешит доступ к файлам с расширением `php` и `css`.

Comment: ответ как всегда гениально прост - спасибо

Comment: @LenovoID Рад был помочь. Синтаксис у `mod_rewrite` действительно малопонятный... Долго привыкал...

Comment: а как писать правильно вот это   ^.*$  ( даже ссылка не помешает  на ресурс с пояснениями )

Comment: @LenovoID Не очень понял вопрос, постараюсь оветить в меру своего понимания. Это регулярное выражение (RegEx, RegExp, Regular Expression), которое описывает условие, при котором срабатывает переход. В данном случае оно означает "всё, что угодно" и его можно немного компактифицировать и записать так: `.*`. Что касается пояснений, то лучшая, ИМХО, документация на `mod_rewrite` у его разработчика: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html. А регулярные выражения - это очень обширная тема. Начать можно с википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения

Comment: я понял про это , но теперя если ссылаюсь на страницу в это папке то происходит редирект на index - спасибо так и должно быть ! но вопрос php сценарий будет срабатывать если в эту директорию поместить php скрипты ?

Comment: @LenovoID Перенаправление будет происходить в любом случае, независимо от содержимого директории.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33433/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-kff).